# Is threading in PHP efficient or not?

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm writing a php code for a web server where it's required to do some heavy duty processes when requested before returning the results to the users.
My question is: does the apache server creates a separate thread/process for each client or should I use multi-threading to separate them?
The processes include calling the execution of other applications through cmd and downloading files to the server.

Comment: It sounds like you need a job/queue server rather than multi-threading (even if you use multi-threading you'll be launching in the context of the web server user, which may not be what you want). Look at Gearman, Resque, etc. [Here's a comprehensive list](http://queues.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well every request to the web server is a separate process which will try to use a free core from the CPU, and if there isn't a free one currently, it will go on a que and wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multithreading in php with apache within a single web request. You simply can't. Usually at each request apache forks a new O.S. process.
This is configurable, but typically chosen when working with php, since many methods of php standard library are not thread safe.

When I had to handle heavy computation I always choose to make the user request asynchronous, and let a third-process daemon to do the actual computation in background. In this case, after the user request, I let the client to poll the daemon (through others web-requests) to know when the computation is done.

Comment: What if I told you that you can have multithreading in PHP, even with Apache. What would happen then? Would you google first to confirm that you might be wrong or would we argue? However, you are correct with the other half of your answer

Comment: I googled it years ago when I was needing it, and I won't do it again today, but i'm happy to know I could be wrong

Comment: Just so I apologize first - I realize I might have been rude with initial comment. Using pthreads extension, PHP developers are able to thread userland PHP code. The reason I commented was because I often stumble in weird arguments language X vs PHP, one of the comments is usually "lack of threading".  It just means that I like when potentially influential SO members get the facts straight so we don't spread outdated information. However, even if one can use threads in PHP, that doesn't mean they should - which is why async approach is nearly always better.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have one final question: does apache fork a new thread for each POST request even if it was sent by the same client? I was thinking of running my code as a web service that receives such requests from single or multiple clients, but it needs a new thread for each request. if there is another or better way, please advise me.

Comment: As answered, yes: apache with php forks at each POST.